# Azure capture event from Eventhub not capturing as per size window

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

While creating Eventhub, I have specified size window  10MB , time window as 5min, but while capturing events from Eventhub, when buffer size reaches 1Mb , capturing data to storage account even though not reaches to mentioned time window 5min or mentioned size window 10MB.
Given 1 TU, 1Partition as Eventhub configuration.

Could you please tell me why this is happening like this?

Comment: Hi Reddy, First, when it reaches 1MB, it's less than 10 MB, so it will not be caputured for the size window 10 MB condition. And how long when buffer size reaches 1MB? if it takes less than 5 minutes, it should not be captured.

Comment: Hello, can you provide some info about my question?

Comment: its working... Thanks...Ivan

Comment: Hi Reddy, I added an answer to this post. If it helps, could you please help mark it as answer, as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When [Capture data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-enable-through-portal#capture-data-to-an-azure-storage-account), there're 2 conditions: Size window and Time window, and whichever comes first would win.

For your question:

First, when it reaches 1MB, it's less than 10 MB, so it will not be caputured for the size window 10 MB condition. And how long when buffer size reaches 1MB? if it takes less than 5 minutes, it should not be captured.